# crawling web data selenium python

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, click, element

i tried to get content in this location. but there is only blank show. Please help me.
this is the elment: Đã bán 74k/tháng
This is my code.

```
print(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.r6HknA+uEPGHT"))
```

in this website:
https://shopee.vn/search?keyword=iphone&page=0&sortBy=sales
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the text ***Đã bán 74k/tháng*** ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://shopee.vn/search?keyword=iphone&page=0&sortBy=sales")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.row.shopee-search-item-result__items > div > a div[data-sqe='rating'] +div"))).text)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Đã bán 74k/tháng
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

Comment: tks you so much! i added some point to get all the text
[my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.row.shopee-search-item-result__items > div > a div[data-sqe='rating'] +div")]